# How does curly brace initialization work?

Tags: c++, oop, initialization

First of all, I've found the term "initializer list" being used for two seemingly different things: Initializing classes using curly braces like this `Foo foo{1}` and writing constructors using this syntax `Foo::Foo(int test) : m_test(test)`. Are these two connected or am I just mixing things up?

Now to my actual question. [I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926) that the curly brace initialization does not allow narrowing. However, that can't be the only difference.

```cpp
struct Test {
    int one;
    int two;
};

int main() {
    Test test{1, 2};
}
```

This code works, even though `Test::Test(int,int)` is declared nowhere. So what exactly does the curly brace initialization do differently from normal initialization? Is it just syntactic sugar or are there deeper reasons as to why it exists?

Comment: *"Are these two connected"* Not really. The first one is a "braced-init-list", the second one is "member initializer list".

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569038/list-initialization-initializer-list-and-related-questions-in-c

Comment: This is [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).